# Android UI elements for messaging i.e like Google Talk

Tags: android

Are there specific UI elements for messaging within android apps? For example the elements used in the Google Talk app.

Thanks

Comment: Which elements are you referring too, precisely? Can you perhaps highlight some on a screenshot? I don't recall there being anything out of the ordinary on the GTalk app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not come across any specific UI Widgets for chat applications, the only thing that is not ordinary is the Chat-ListView which could be a modified ListView or a custom view. For me it looks like it's a custom View. Other UI elements are just: ActionBar, ViewPager and an EditText at the bottom.